# CSS. Динамическое изменение класса

Tags: javascript, html, css

Привет!

Как можно изменить содержимое css класса динамически, например есть класс:

```
.active{
    color: green; 
}
```

Нужно в определенный момент времени, например при клике на какой-либо элемент, изменить этот класс:

```
 .active{
    color: red; 
 }
```

Это вообще возможно сделать, и какими способами?

P.S. Нужно изменить именно сам класс css, добавлять новый класс не нужно, также как и не нужно обращаться к свойству style у элемента в js, такие решения не подходят.

Comment: Используйте события элемента с javascript , удобно c Jquery менять состояние стиля. надо поискать (google). https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-cookbook/9781449390211/ch12s16.html

Comment: чтобы получить помощь нужно показать, как вы сами пытались это сделать. давайте ваш код, будем разбираться.

Comment: Это можно сделать и средствами css и js,которые Вы указали метками в вопросе.

Comment: На многих сайтах есть такие панельки http://joxi.ru/n2YdjZMcjQPzLm, когда пользователь может сам изменять цвета содержимого. Допустим, есть некий элемент `<div class="active">text</div>`, сейчас текст в нем синего цвета, при изменении цвета в этой панели, у этого элемента остается все то же самое, тот же класс, атрибута style нет, но при этом цвет текста изменяется в самом классе active, т.е. изменился сам класс active, записанный в стилях до загрузки страницы.

Comment: Shillkas, о какой панели вы говорите? о панели разработчика?

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".elementClass" ).click(function() {
   $( ".elementClass" ).css( "color", "red" );
});
```

ну или

```
 $( ".elementClass" ).click(function() {
       $( ".elementClass" ).addClass( "myClass" );
    });
```

Comment: А можно ли изменить css класс, т.е. у конкретного класса изменить свойства по клику после загрузки страницы?

Comment: то есть внести изменения в сам файл css что ли

Comment: никогда о таком не слышал. да и зачем?